# Get error when convert large PDF file to image using imagick

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick

I got an error when i try to convert large pdf file to image. There are no errors when i convert regular pdf but got error when converts large files.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Postscript delegate failed
```

If any idea then please give me solution thank you.

Comment: This may help you http://www.herikstad.net/2010/05/postscript-delegate-failed-for.html

Comment: Did you install Ghostscript? Its required by ImageMagick to interpret Postscript and PDF.

Comment: Yes i've already install Ghostscript.